# Bash mixing for loop and if then expression gives bad results

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, for-loop

I am a beginner with the linux shell and scripts and I get some weird results when doing this

```
#!/bin/bash

sysarch=( "x86" "amd64" )

arch_options=""
for i in "${sysarch[@]}"
do
    :
    if [ $i=="amd64" ]; then
        arch_options="-m64 -D ACIS64"
    elif [ $i=="x86" ]; then
        arch_options="-m32"
    fi
    echo $arch_options
done

exec $SHELL
```

So, I have an array with two architecture types. I loop through them and I want to get the corresponding GCC options for each one. The problem is that `$arch_options` is always `"-m64 -D ACIS64"`, regardless of `$i` and I don't understand why.

Comment: You need spaces around `$i=="amd64"`. Also a good practice to quote your variables.

Comment: And the `:` in the `for` loop is completely redundant (useless).

Comment: And `==` in the `test`, i.e. `[` command doesn't make much sense.  Use `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you say, it prints the same value each time:

```
$ ./foo
-m64 -D ACIS64
-m64 -D ACIS64
```

So let's take a look at it:

```
$ shellcheck foo
In foo line 9:
    if [ $i=="amd64" ]; then
         ^-- SC2077: You need spaces around the comparison operator.

In foo line 11:
    elif [ $i=="x86" ]; then
           ^-- SC2077: You need spaces around the comparison operator.

In foo line 17:    
exec $SHELL
     ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
```

And fix the problems:

```
#!/bin/bash

sysarch=( "x86" "amd64" )

arch_options=""
for i in "${sysarch[@]}"
do
    :
    if [ $i == "amd64" ]; then
        arch_options="-m64 -D ACIS64"
    elif [ $i == "x86" ]; then
        arch_options="-m32"
    fi
    echo $arch_options
done

exec "$SHELL"
```

And voila:

```
$ ./foo
-m32
-m64 -D ACIS64
```

Comment: You didn't quote the debugging was done at [ShellCheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) `;)`

Comment: Technically, it wasn't. He ran `shellcheck` locally.

Comment: @chepner I made that comment since his answer included `^-- SC2086:` which is seen on ShellCheck.net.